# Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $m$, and let the number $s$ be relatively prime to $m$. Prove that if $a^s = b^s$ then it follows that $a = b$.

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a cyclic group of order $m$, and let the number $s$ be relatively prime to $m$. Prove that if $a^s = b^s$ then it follows that $a = b$.

Let $st+mr=1$ then we have a = $a^{st+mr}=a^{st}=b^{st}=b^{st+mr}=b$.

Is this correct?

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Thanks im new at this @NormalHuman

Comment: You need to add an a= on the left but your reasoning is flawless.

Comment: but its correct help me please ? @Justpassingby

Comment: It is, don't worry.

Comment: Of course it's correct

Comment: Since $G$ is cyclic of order $m$ and thus abelian, you might find the argument clearer if you express things additively rather than multiplicatively.

Comment: what do u mean by that? @hardmath

Comment: We often use + as the group operation for abelian groups (groups where the group operation is *commutative*).  In any case your group $G$ is (isomorphic to) the integers modulo $m$, so you can express the argument  in integer arithmetic.

Comment: i know that but i dont know how to do it, i thought that this way is easier @hardmath

Comment: I've written out your argument using the additive notation, as a Community Wiki answer, so you can see if the computation looks more familiar that way (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same argument, presented using additive notation (+) rather than multiplicative notation for the group operation.  [This is conventional when a group is abelian, and indeed all cyclic groups are abelian.]  Then instead of writing $a^s = b^s$ for some integer $s$, we would instead say $sa = sb$, where the expression $sa$ is an abbreviation for $a$ added to itself $s$ times (or for the additive inverse of a similar expression when $s$ is negative).  Of course we would write the identity element as zero in this convention.

Thus $a\in G$, a cyclic group of order $m$, implies that:

$$ ma \equiv a + a + \ldots + a = 0 $$

As the OP notes in the problem statement, if $s$ is coprime to $m$, then there exist integers $t$ and $r$ such that $st + mr = 1$.  Thus:

$$ (st + mr)a = a $$

and:

$$ (st + mr)b = b $$

Therefore we can use $sa = sb$ and $ma = mb = 0$ to prove:

$$ a = (st + mr)a = t(sa) + r(ma) = t(sb) + r(mb) = b $$

As a way of persuading oneself that there is not some overlooked "trick" in using the additive notation, one can consider that $G$ must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, the group of integers modulo $m$.  In that context the above computation becomes simply a statement about residue mod $m$.